# JAVA Apache POI Excel: add borders to cell range

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

Is there a way to add borders to a cellrange using Java with Apache POI?

Like A1:B2 should get a top-bottom-left-right thick border - style?

I know how to create & apply styles to single cells and I might iterate trough the cells and apply the appropriate styles but I'm sure there's an easier way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been able to figure it out. There is actually a sample on the apache poi page I just didn't find with the keywords I've been searching with.

```
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf(A1:B2);
short borderStyle = CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM;
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderTop(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderRight(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
```

Comment: `CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(firstRow, lastRow, firstCol, lastCol);
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DASHED, region, worksheet);  ...`

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed in 3.16

```
CellRangeAddress region = new CellRangeAddress(6, 8, 1, 10);
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN, region, sheet);
RegionUtil.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN, region, sheet);
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN, region, sheet);
RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN, region, sheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

*RegionUtil* turned all background colors other than white to black in my case. 
This is my workaround:

```
public final class BorderUtils {

    public static void setBorder(Sheet sheet, BorderStyle borderStyle, CellRangeAddress region) {
        setBorderTop(sheet, borderStyle, region);
        setBorderBottom(sheet, borderStyle, region);
        setBorderLeft(sheet, borderStyle, region);
        setBorderRight(sheet, borderStyle, region);
    }

    public static void setBorderTop(Sheet sheet, BorderStyle borderStyle, CellRangeAddress region) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(region.getFirstRow());
        for (int i=region.getFirstColumn() ; i<=region.getLastColumn() ; i++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
            CellStyle cellStyle = cloneCellStyle(sheet, cell);
            cellStyle.setBorderTop(borderStyle);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }

    public static void setBorderBottom(Sheet sheet, BorderStyle borderStyle, CellRangeAddress region) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(region.getLastRow());
        for (int i=region.getFirstColumn() ; i<=region.getLastColumn() ; i++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
            CellStyle cellStyle = cloneCellStyle(sheet, cell);
            cellStyle.setBorderBottom(borderStyle);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }

    public static void setBorderLeft(Sheet sheet, BorderStyle borderStyle, CellRangeAddress region) {
        for (int i=region.getFirstRow() ; i<=region.getLastRow() ; i++) {
            Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(region.getFirstColumn());
            CellStyle cellStyle = cloneCellStyle(sheet, cell);
            cellStyle.setBorderLeft(borderStyle);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }

    public static void setBorderRight(Sheet sheet, BorderStyle borderStyle, CellRangeAddress region) {
        for (int i=region.getFirstRow() ; i<=region.getLastRow() ; i++) {
            Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(region.getLastColumn());
            CellStyle cellStyle = cloneCellStyle(sheet, cell);
            cellStyle.setBorderRight(borderStyle);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }

}
```